# How to join a query result with an existing table to perform an UPDATE?

Tags: sql, ms-access

My query looks like this, and I am thinking it is because of the use of `ConcatRelated()`, which concatenates related fields:

```
SELECT C.ID, ConcatRelated(["GameNames", "BaselineQuery", "CC.ID = " & [ID]) AS Games FROM BaselineQuery AS C GROUP BY C.ID
```

The Result Set will look like:

```
ID    GameNames
 1    "A, "B", "C", D"
 2    "A", "B"
 3    "D", "E", "A", "B"
```

My Games Table I want to UPDATE Looks like

```
ID  GameNames
 1     
 2
 3
```

Where GameNames is currently blank and I want to use the ID of the query and the ID of the table to populate GameNames, so 1 in the Games table should be "A", "B", "C", "D".

My UPDATE query says:

```
UPDATE GAMES INNER JOIN CreatedQuery ON Games.ID = CreatedQuery.ID SET Games.GameNames = CreatedQuery.GameNames
```

Ufortunately, Access is telling me this UPDATE query is not an updateable query, which doesn't make much sense to me right now, considering ID is the PK of the Games table and the values are clearly the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't join in non-updateable queries in update queries. Using subqueries also does not work. The entire recordset (all underlying queries and tables) need to be updateable.

However, you can use `DLookUp` to work around the problem:

```
UPDATE GAMES
SET Games.GameNames = DLookUp("GameNames", "CreatedQuery", "ID =" & ID)
```